# Recursion using BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist, bufferedreader

For my comp sci class we were given a problem that I cannot seem to solve. The problem is as follows. We also have to use the flood fill algorithm

> Create a program that reads a text file containing a 15 x 15 grid, which represents human cells. The cells are depicted with a plus sign “+” if they are healthy cells, and a minus sign “-” if they are cancerous. The outside rows and columns of the grid will contain only plus signs “+”." Basically whats going to happen is you need to use recursion to check every item in the txt file and if the character is a "-" then you change it to " " and if the character is "+" you leave it as "+".

This is the code I currently have. So far i've got the text file into an arraylist then made a string array. I'm unsure how to check every value to see if they are a "-" because once i'm able to do that the recursion should be fairly simple. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class Cancer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String[][] grid = new String[14][14];

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("location.txt"));
      String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            lines.add(str);
        }
        String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
  }
}
```

Comment: weird problem. this kind of mapping operation is usually done iteratively. also, the actual question in the text seems to have nothing to do with the title.

Comment: This is not a problem to which recursion is applicable.  Are you _sure_ you were asked to use recursion?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you're better off using a char grid, but lets continue with the String approach:

When you declare your array, you declare its size, so a String array with 15 elements would be declared as `new String[15]`.

I don't really see why you'd need a two-dimensional array of Strings since one String is an entire row (line).
Here's a slightly modified version of your program that reads the lines of the file into a one-dimensional String array, then loops over each char in each row and finds "cancer" (iteratively):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Cancer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String[] grid = new String[15];

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("location.txt"));
      String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
            grid[i] = str;
            i++;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
            String row = grid[x];
            for (int y = 0; y < row.length(); y++) {
                if(row.charAt(y) == '-') {
                    System.out.println("Cancer found at " + x + "," + y);
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Hopefully that gives you an idea of how you can check your input.
There's nothing wrong with the String and charAt-approach (since the 'grid' becomes one-dimensional), it just makes the actual 'algorithm' a little less portable. As others have mentioned, it is a bit weird to solve this using recursion. One way would be to make use of grid coordinates to do recursive calls. Another option is to "chop off" arrays/strings.

Comment: @KEYSER isn't the `grid` array un-required? using `iterator` we can fetch the String

Comment: @KNU Since we only process it once, no, it's not required. But it makes for good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt :

```
package com.college.assignment;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* @author Kunal Krishna
* 
*/
public class Cancer {

public static final String cancerSamplePath = "C://Users//Kunal//workspace//Cancer///src//com//college//assignment//location.txt";
static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    readFile();

    displayFile();

    System.out.println("\n========================================");
    if (searchInfectedCells(lines) == 0) {
        System.out.println("None of the Cells are damaged");
    }
    System.out.println("========================================"); 
}

private static void displayFile() {
    for (String string : lines) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

private static int searchInfectedCells(List<String> lines) {
    int infectedCellRowPosition = 0;
    int totalInfectedCells = 0;
    for (String row : lines) {
        infectedCellRowPosition++;
        for (int infectedCellColPosition = 0; infectedCellColPosition < row
                .length(); infectedCellColPosition++) {
            if (row.charAt(infectedCellColPosition) == '-') {
                                    totalInfectedCells++;
                System.out.println("Cancerous cell found at location ("
                        + infectedCellRowPosition + ","
                        + infectedCellColPosition + ")");
            }
        }
    }
    return totalInfectedCells;
}

public static void readFile() {

    BufferedReader in;
    String str;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cancerSamplePath));
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(str);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
        System.out.println("Cancer sample data missing.");
        fne.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**OUTPUT** (also displays input) :

```
+++++++++++++++
+-+++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++
+-+++++++++++-+
+++++++++++++++

========================================
Cancerous cell found at location (2,1)
Cancerous cell found at location (14,1)
Cancerous cell found at location (14,13)
========================================
```